# How to design a PDA for the language of words with s a's, t b's and s⋅t c's?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I have the language

$\qquad L=\{ a^s b^t c^m \mid s,t,m \; \in \; \mathbb{N^{+}} \text{ and } t<4, s \cdot t=m\}$.

How do I go about designing a PDA for it ?

I can't figure out a way to deal with $m$.

Comment: If you can design a PDA for $t=1$, $t=2$ and $t=3$ , could you then design PDA for your original problem ?

Comment: You mean 3 different PDA ?

Comment: yes 3 different PDA.

Comment: I guess it would work since It covers all the cases.

Comment: Ok then your problem is reduced to design a PDA for say only $t=1$.

Comment: Why reduced to only t=1 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31468/discussion-between-guillaume-and-sasha).

Comment: I'll design it for t=1, t=2 , t=3. Now I'm trying to understand how to combine those solutions

Comment: To solve it I used an PDA  doing this : firts b-> if c then c,a;E,  second b-> if c then c,aa;E, third b-> if c then c,aaa;E.

Comment: Please edit the question to show your progress so far.  Don't just put that in the comments -- people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand your question.  Following sasha's advice, I suggest you edit hte question to show a PDA for the case $t=1$, a PDA for the case $t=2$, and a PDA for $t=3$, then ask about what to do next.  Do try to be a lot more careful in describing/defining your PDA: take your time and write it out carefully and precisely.

Comment: And please do *not* undo my edit of your title. This amount of LaTeX is harmful in titles (doesn't work well with many RSS readers, for instance). If you think you have a better clear-text title, go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was: how to remember the amount of b and use it to count number of c. Well I guess I was lucky since there were only 3 possible cases. t=1, t=2 and t=3.

Here is my solution:

[image]

It might not be optimal, feel free to propose changes or better solutions.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question.  One small comment: *"But what to do if t was for all values of N+."* - Please don't use answers to ask follow-up questions (or request feedback on your solution).  Instead, if you have a follow-up question, you should ask a new, separate question.